# Mass delete records from custom object via apex class

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

Aim- I want to delete any record within custom object training__c where the created date is greater than 6 months from today's date.

I would like to run this job daily.

I apologise if the following below has errors I just wrote this on my iPhone, Does the following logic below make sense ?

Looking forward to your help

List  listsObject = [Select Id from training  where  Createddate <= ( Current Date - 6 months) 
    Limit 9000];Delete

Answer (score 0):

Yo can select by using Date Literals such as LAST_N_DAYS 
e.g.

```
 List listsObject = [Select Id from training where CreatedDate <= LAST_N_DAYS:180];
 delete listsObject;
```

More about [Date Literals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)